# Image crop after rotate by canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I have a html5 canvas. I want  to draw/rotate the image in the canvas and image size does not change.I set width/height of canvas base on size of image.I have a problem to rotate an image.َ
After rotate image,the red triangles was crop.
In below link  a example showing this in problem.Please help.
http://jsfiddle.net/zsh64/6ZsCz/76/

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var angleInDegrees = 0;
      var image = document.createElement("img");
      image.onload = function () {
          canvas.width = image.width;
          canvas.height = image.height;
          ctx.drawImage(image, 0,0);
      };
      image.src = "Images/rotate.png";
      $("#R").click(function () {
          angleInDegrees += 90;
          drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
      });
      $("#L").click(function () {
          angleInDegrees -= 90;
          drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
      });
      function drawRotated(degrees) {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          ctx.save();
          ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
          ctx.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
          ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.width / 2);
          ctx.restore();
      }
```

Comment: Well, if I take a piece of a4 paper in portrait mode and I measure it's dimensions, I'd tell you it was 210x297mm. If on the other hand, I measured the dimensions of the same piece of paper in landscape mode, I'd tell you that it was 297x210mm. See where I'm going here? The size of the bounding-box of your image is orientation-dependant. With integer angles of 90°, you've only got 2 orientations to consider - it's this way, or its that way. (you can simply swap the dimensions - no need for any trig functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you rotate your image, you can recalculate the boundingbox needed to contain it.

[image][image]

This code will takes width/height/rotation angle and returns the new bounding box size:

```
function newSize(w,h,a){
    var rads=a*Math.PI/180;
    var c = Math.cos(rads);
    var s = Math.sin(rads);
    if (s < 0) { s = -s; }
    if (c < 0) { c = -c; }
    size.width = h * s + w * c;
    size.height = h * c + w * s ;
}
```

Here is example code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/h65yr/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #containerDiv{
          border: 1px solid red;
          position:absolute;
          top:100px;
          left:100px;
        }
        #canvas{
          border: 1px solid green;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

$(function(){
         var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
         var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
         var imgWidth=200;
         var imgHeight=300;
         var size={width:imgWidth, height:imgHeight};
         var rotation=0;
         var deg2Rad=Math.PI/180;
         var count1=0;
         var count2=0;

          var img=new Image();
          img.onload=function(){
              imgWidth=img.width;
              imgHeight=img.height;
              size={width:imgWidth, height:imgHeight};
              draw();
          }
          img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/Rotate.png";

      function draw(){
         canvas.width=size.width;
         canvas.height=size.height; 

         // calculate the centerpoint of the canvas
         var cx=canvas.width/2;
         var cy=canvas.height/2;
         var info=document.getElementById("info");
         info.innerHTML="canvas size: "+(count1++)+": "+cx+" / "+cy;

         // draw the rect in the center of the newly sized canvas
         ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
         ctx.fillStyle="rgba(216,216,150,1.0)";
         ctx.translate(cx,cy);
         ctx.rotate(rotation * deg2Rad);
         ctx.drawImage(img,-imgWidth/2,-imgHeight/2);
      }

      document.getElementById("rotate").addEventListener("click", rotateClicked, false);

      function rotateClicked(e){
        rotation+=30;
        draw();
      }

      document.getElementById("resize").addEventListener("click", resizeClicked, false);

      function resizeClicked(e){
        rotation+=30;
        newSize(imgWidth,imgHeight,rotation);
        draw();
      }

      function newSize(w,h,a){
        var rads=a*Math.PI/180;
        var c = Math.cos(rads);
        var s = Math.sin(rads);
        if (s < 0) { s = -s; }
        if (c < 0) { c = -c; }
        size.width = h * s + w * c;
        size.height = h * c + w * s ;
    }

});

    </script>

</head>

<body>
<button id="rotate">Rotate without resize</button>
<button id="resize">Resize with resize</button>
<p id=info></p>

<div id="containerDiv">
    <canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Issues

There are two issues you are facing:

1. There is not enough room in the canvas to do a rotation
2. You are drawing the image at center of rotation rather than center of image

## Solutions

To properly size your canvas you can use maximum boundary of the rotated rectangle. To find this boundary you can do one of two things:

If you only need to rotate per 90 degrees:

```
var length = Math.max(img.width, img.height);
```

If you want to use free angle:

```
var length = Math.sqrt(img.width * img.width + img.height * img.height);
```

Then use one of these results to set the size of the canvas:

```
canvas.width = canvas.height = length; /// both has same length
```

Next thing is to properly draw in the image. After rotation you need to translate back as the image is always drawn from its upper left corner:

```
var pivot = length * 0.5;

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(pivot, pivot);
ctx.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width * 0.5, -image.height * 0.5);
ctx.restore();
```

It's important you use the pivot of the image to offset it back as the image will here be of a different size than canvas.

The result from this **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/gnaqA/)** here:

[image: Bounds of rotated rectangle]

Answer (score 1):

change the parameter of drawImage

```
ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height/ 2);
```

Comment: Or (to be more consistent with the .translate method call): `ctx.drawImage(image, -canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);`