# how to rotate an image with a prefix data:image/jpg;base64 using jQueryRotate.js

Tags: jquery, jsp

How to rotate an image with the prefix data:image/jpg;base64 and with c:forEach using jqueryRotate plugin. I have a jquery dialog box, In that dialog box I have these images

```
<div style="display: none;" id="${Item.type}Div">
<c:forEach var="itemList" items="${Item.image}"
varStatus="listItemStatus">
<img width="500px" height="600px" id="imageRotate" 
style="align: left;" src="data:image/jpg;base64,${itemList}" />
</c:forEach>
</div>

<span class="rotateClockWise"><img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/rotate_icon.jpg"/>"
width="30" height="30" title="Rotate Clockwise" alt="Rotate Clockwise" border="0"
 style="float: right;" /></span>
```

script

```
$(".rotateClockWise").click(function(){
     $("#imageRotate").rotate(180); 
});
```

but like this the image inside the dialog popup is not rotating. Any help would be great. How to rotate an image under c:forEach with Object.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
// using css3 rotate 
$(".rotateClockWise").click(function(){
var angle = 180;   
     $("#imageRotate").css({
         "transform":"rotate("+angle+"deg)",
         "-ms-transform":"rotate("+angle+"deg)",/* IE 9 */
         "-webkit-transform":"rotate("+angle+"deg)" /* Safari and Chrome */
      }); 
});
```

there is another solutions using html5 canvas take a look here 
[Javascript function to Rotate a base 64 image by X degrees and return new base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040360/javascript-function-to-rotate-a-base-64-image-by-x-degrees-and-return-new-base64)