# React-Native : How to rotate base 64 image

Tags: react-native, base64, image-rotation

I have PNG image in `base64` format which will be saved in server, But before saving into server image need to be rotated.

I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040360/javascript-function-to-rotate-a-base-64-image-by-x-degrees-and-return-new-base64), but it doesn't seem possible in `react-native`.

Is there any way in `react-native` to rotate `base64` image?

I tried using [gm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm), But i end up with lot of errors in `node_modules`. Has any one else tried this package?

Comment: Should the user be able to rotate it, or not? If you always want to rotate your image by for example 90 degree, you can just do the processing on the server.

Comment: @Tim, User will not have access to rotate. SO, Can you tell me how to do this process in server it self?

Comment: @Kishore what technology do you use in the server side?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-rotate

Answer (score 4):

There is a package [react-native-image-rotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-rotate)
 you can rotate any image including base64

**Installation**

First install the package via npm

```
$ npm install react-native-image-rotate
```

then use rnpm to link native libraries

```
$ react-native link react-native-image-rotate
```

**usage**

```
static rotateImage(
    uri: string,
    angle: number,
    success: (uri: string) => void,
    failure: (error: Object) => void
  ) : void
```

**Example**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View,Image, TouchableHighlight,Text } from 'react-native';

import ImageRotate from 'react-native-image-rotate';


const string = 'Your base64 image here' 
    export default class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            image: string,
            currentAngle: 0,
            width: 150,
            height: 240,
        };

        this.rotate = this.rotate.bind(this);

    }
    rotate = (angle) => {
        const nextAngle = this.state.currentAngle + angle;
        ImageRotate.rotateImage(
            string,
            nextAngle,
            (uri) => {
                console.log(uri, 'uri')
                this.setState({
                    image: uri,
                    currentAngle: nextAngle,
                    width: this.state.height,
                    height: this.state.width,
                });
            },
            (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        );
    }


    render(){

        return (
            <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center'}}>
                <Image source={{uri: this.state.image}} style={{width: 300, height: 300}}/>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={() => this.rotate(90)}
                    style={styles.button}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.text}>ROTATE CW</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is My research and what i have found https://aboutreact.com/react-native-rotate-image-view-using-animation/

```
npm install -g react-native-cli 
react-native init myproject 

cd myproject
```

then .js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Animated, Image, Easing } from 'react-native';
export default class App extends React.Component {
    RotateValueKeeper: any;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.RotateValueKeeper = new Animated.Value(0);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.ImageRotateStarterFunction();
  }
  ImageRotateStarterFunction() {
    this.RotateValueKeeper.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(this.RotateValueKeeper, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 3000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    }).start(() => this.ImageRotateStarterFunction());
  }
  render() {
    const MyRotateData = this.RotateValueKeeper.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
    });
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.Image
          style={{
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            transform: [{ rotate: MyRotateData }],
          }}
          source={{
            uri:
              'https://aboutreact.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/logo1024.png',
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#C2C2C2',
  },
});
```

then

Android

```
react-native run-android
```

iOS

```
react-native run-ios
```

Comment: Purpose here is not to simply rotate the image on the app. The image itself has to change, meaning the image data needs to change so that even server will have the rotated image and not just fake rotating on front-end.